# Letter in conditional formatting Excel

Tags: excel, conditional-statements

i've a litte question:

Is there a way to insert automatically a letter into the cell in conditional formatting?

That if condition is true = there is a "F" in the cell?

Thanks!

Comment: You would have tp convert the TRUE to a 1 with a double unary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("*Paid*",E3,1),"F"),0)
```

I have this situation where I search "Paid" in column E3 and if exist I have added value F in required column. You can use this. I you can't get it. This explain your condition I will give the answer.